# My Python script reads wrong RGB values - OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to write code to recognize colors from HSV values of pixels. Color recognision works very good but sometimes it gets wrong values (I've checked them in plot)

The image I'm working with:
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/shapes_and_colors.jpg

Here is my dictionary with values of colors in HSV color space:

```py
# colors in Hue Saturation Value color space
colors = {
    'red': np.array([0, 100, 100]),
    'orange': np.array([30, 100, 100]),
    'yellow': np.array([60, 100, 100]),
    'green': np.array([120, 100, 100]),
    'blue': np.array([240, 100, 100]),
    'violet': np.array([270, 100, 100]),
    'pink': np.array([330, 100, 100]),
}
```

Color Recognition function which returns string color name (rgb_to_hsv works good values are correct - I've checked it on http://colorizer.org/)

```py
def colorRecognition(pixelRGB):
    pixelHSV = rgb_to_hsv(pixelRGB)
    if pixelHSV[1] < 10:
        if pixelHSV[2] < 12:
            return 'black'
        elif pixelHSV[2] > 80:
            return 'white'
        else:
            return 'gray'
    else:
        diff = np.empty(shape=(0, 2), dtype=([('values', np.dtype(int)), ('names', type(colors.keys()))]))

        for name, value in colors.items():
            abs_diff = abs(int(pixelHSV[0]) - int(value[0]))
            diff = np.append(diff, np.array([(abs_diff, name)], dtype=diff.dtype))
        color = np.sort(diff)[0][1]
        if pixelHSV[2] < 10:
            return 'black'
        else:
            return color
```

The core of the script:

```py
img = cv.imread('img/shapes_and_colors.jpg')
rgb = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
blurred = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv.threshold(blurred, 70, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

points = np.empty(shape=(0, 4))

for c in cnts:
    M = cv.moments(c)
    cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

    points = np.append(points, [[cX, cY, rgb[cX, cY], colorRecognition(rgb[cX, cY])]], axis=0)
```

Output of the script:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP2hp.jpg <- Image with numerised shapes and recognized colors

```py
1.X: 239, Y:421
color: blue
rbg: [  0 130 224]
hsv: [205, 100, 87]

2.X: 344, Y:451
color: gray
rbg: [35 34 32]
hsv: [39, 8, 13]

3.X: 433, Y:398
color: red
rbg: [43 37 37]
hsv: [0, 13, 16]

4.X: 155, Y:377
color: black
rbg: [20 16 15]
hsv: [12, 25, 7]

5.X: 395, Y:330
color: orange
rbg: [255 157  94]
hsv: [23, 63, 100]

6.X: 220, Y:328
color: blue
rbg: [22 25 30]
hsv: [217, 26, 11]

7.X: 291, Y:312
color: yellow
rbg: [229 214  73]
hsv: [54, 68, 89]

8.X: 491, Y:263
color: gray
rbg: [44 44 42]
hsv: [60, 4, 17]

9.X: 340, Y:244
color: green
rbg: [32 37 33]
hsv: [132, 13, 14]

10.X: 410, Y:229
color: blue
rbg: [  1 142 234]
hsv: [203, 99, 91]

11.X: 144, Y:229
color: black
rbg: [19 18 16]
hsv: [40, 15, 7]

12.X: 338, Y:182
color: yellow
rbg: [36 35 31]
hsv: [48, 13, 14]

13.X: 199, Y:171
color: yellow
rbg: [244 230  81]
hsv: [54, 66, 95]

14.X: 266, Y:174
color: yellow
rbg: [234 218  81]
hsv: [53, 65, 91]

15.X: 238, Y:98
color: yellow
rbg: [250 246  95]
hsv: [58, 62, 98]

16.X: 132, Y:111
color: yellow
rbg: [234 218  71]
hsv: [54, 69, 91]

17.X: 365, Y:102
color: gray
rbg: [37 36 34]
hsv: [39, 8, 14]
```

Comment: Check how you're picking the point where you grab the colour. The problem is not with colour recognition or with OpenCV giving "wrong RGB" but with you taking a wrong point. Draw the points on the image, see where they show up, do the maths to get them right.

Comment: array may use coordinates `Y,X` (row,column) instead of `X,Y`

Comment: @furas Thank you very much I haven't seen this bug

Answer (score 1):

> array may use coordinates Y,X (row,column) instead of X,Y – furas